# How to test my simple mysql login form for sql injection?

Tags: php

I have created a simple login form for a project in PHP and mySQL. I read about security and info about SQL Injections and XSS.
How can I test my form with these stuff ? I mean where I put it?
I found something like this `' or 1=1–` and SQL queries like

```
SELECT fieldlist
  FROM table
 WHERE field = '$EMAIL';
```

I know it's a silly question, but I don't know the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for input `input = $EMAIL` the value `asdf' or '1'='1` in the input and submit and see if you get true result or not.

So the query generated is

```
SELECT fieldlist
  FROM table
 WHERE field = 'asdf' or '1'='1';
```

To check if password is not empty or not.

```
if(!isset($_POST['password']))
```

Also doing this would be more better if

```
$username = trim($_POST['username']); //also turn magic quotes
            //or add slashes to prevent sql injection

$password = md5(trim($_POST['username'])); //encrypt the password


SELECT *
FROM user
WHERE username = `$username` AND
password = `$password` LIMIT 1;

if(mysql_num_rows($result)) //if the count is 1, then, the the user exists
//do the login
```

Comment: On the username or password field ?

Comment: @Punkis on both, also check if you have magic quotes turned off or on

Comment: Another small question. I have a page that you put a password. Then the landing page checks if the password (abcdef) is the same with the one i wrote in the form. abcdef is not encoded, just a simple if statement.

Comment: @Punkis well, if it is not encoded, the i guess it is more vulnerable to sql injection. Better to use php  `md5` then mysql's. Sure there will not be sql injection.

Comment: I accepted your answer, thanks for the info. My last question it was about a simple `if ($_POST['txt'] != $password)` login form.

Comment: @Punkis are you check if password is not empty or .. well i wouldn't do that way way. see update above.

Answer (score 0):

You'd submit suspicious strings into your login form.

From there that string `' or 1=1-` (or whatever you want to test) will be sent to your server, and PHP, if not set up properly, will send that string straight into your MySQL database, where if it's valid SQL, it will be executed.

Comment: Hi, on username or password box ?

Comment: Another small question. I have a page that you put a password. Then the landing page checks if the password (abcdef) is the same with the one i wrote in the form. abcdef is not encoded, just a simple if statement.

Comment: soudl i sanitize data also if the query is an UPDATE or an INSERT INTO? i mean, i believe that thse two last have the WHERE that prevents messing around right? so can we say that the sanitation is important in SELECT queries ultimetely?

Comment: It doesn't matter what the SQL query is; they're all potentially vulnerable

Answer (score 0):

You would enter in the malicious code through the form itself, so that it gets sent to PHP, and then to MySQL. If the malicious code alters your query, then your code would be vulnerable to SQL injection. Take a look at `mysql_real_escape_string()`. Also, give this a read, to help you get started:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection
- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php